# Hide files from WhatsApp's possible attachments

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, cache, attachments

I have a problem. I have some files in my android phone which I don't want to be shown on WhatsApp attachment possibilities. I created the `.nomedia` file inside the directory where the files are but WhatsApp keeps showing them. I changed the directory's name and even clear the WhatsApp cache however, when I try to attach a file WhatsApp keeps showing the directory with the old name and showing the thumbnails of the files even though the files can't be shared (since they don't exists anymore).

WhatsApp doesn't  "see" the directory with the new name, however, I want to erase the thumbnails as well. Is there any possibility that doesn't imply to reinstall/clear the data of WhatsApp?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings → Apps → Then make sure you set the filter to see all applications (include system).

Find *Media Storage* in the list and then press "clear data". Reboot. Wait for a while for database to regenerate.  That should fix the thumbnail problem.

The new directory created should have `.nomedia` added to it or the folder name should start with a `.` (dot), before doing above step ,  else you will have the earlier problem of hiding photos